# Creating 2 AUTO _INCREMENT columns in the same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Car
    (
     CarID          INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
     CarBrand        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
     InsuranceNumber INT NOT NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY (CarID))AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I want `InsuranceNumber` auto incremented just like `CarID` but
I know there cannot be 2 auto incremented columns at the same time but I did some research and found out that I can do this with creating a 
`trigger`. I did tried my own but I couldn't manage to do what I want to.

I did tried something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER car_trigger AFTER INSERT ON Car
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE Car SET Car.CarID = Car.InsuranceNumber
```

But I get a syntax error. What should I do ?

Comment: You should ask a question that includes the code for your trigger.

Comment: Let's see.... You want two columns in your table having the same value, right? Why would anyone wish to do something like that?

Comment: @FDavidov Because I want to see `CarID` and `InsuranceNumber` in the same table so I can understand which car has which Insurance number thats why.

Comment: But, from your phrasing, both numbers are going to be the same, will they not?

Comment: @FDavidov thats not really important actually what I really want is when something inserted into the table I want the `InsuranceNumber` column act like it has `AUTO_INCREMENT` so that I don't need to insert values to the `InsuranceNumber` column manually.

Comment: OK, Understood. What about using sequences and have one field as IDENTITY while the other as not null and a default = `Sequence_Name.NextValue`? (you will need to check the syntax of how to get next value of a pre-defined sequence). This should work I think...

Comment: @FDavidov I tried what you said but when I tried to change `InsuranceNumber` into a sequence using `IDENTITY` it gives an error because of the `IDENTITY`. I checked the MySQL 8.0 Manual but there is no such thing as `IDENTITY`. `IDENTITY` exists in **MSSQL** and equivalent of it is `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL.

Comment: Just for completeness, the only database I've found that implements multiple auto-increment columns per table is PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Yagimutsu, please define a table with a two column: One of type INT and set as IDENTIFY(1,1), the second of type CHAR(1) and nullable. Whenever you need a new insurance number, insert a new record into that table and fetch the new identity (first field; note, this can be done WITHOUT SELECT MAX!!!!).

Comment: [This might help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin)

Comment: @FDavidov I already tried that. Problem is that in phpmyadmin when I try to define column which is an INT and set as IDENTIFY(1,1) I got a syntax error because of IDENTITY. There no such thing like that in MySQL , not anymore. There is only AUTO_INCREMENT that works like IDENTITY please read mySQL 8.0 Manual.

Comment: @ThomasG after reading this and some other posts about my problem. I decided to not define a table with 2 auto columns because it has more disadvantages than its advantages , thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you asked about is a syntax error in your trigger code.

The solution is to use the special keyword `NEW` instead of the table name.

```
CREATE TRIGGER car_trigger AFTER INSERT ON Car
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE Car SET NEW.CarID = NEW.InsuranceNumber
```

But you should know this won't work if you're trying to copy one auto-increment column to the other, because you can't change the values of `NEW.*` columns in an `AFTER` trigger. The row has already been inserted and it's too late to change values.

But in a `BEFORE` trigger, the auto-increment value has not yet been generated, and the auto-increment column will still be NULL.

The only way to make something equivalent to "two auto-increment columns" is to generate an auto value not using `AUTO_INCREMENT` but with some other mechanism, so you can supply the value to the row as you execute your SQL statement.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Beacuse of the disadvantages of creating a table with 2 auto incremented columns I would prefer to have 1 auto incremented column and for the other column I will insert the values manually. Thanks for your answer, sir.